# Sbt: migrate from 0.13.x to 1.x

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a project which is compiled using the following:

```
sbt.version=0.13.16
```

And the content of the build.sbt is:

```
name := "aName"

version := "1.2"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion
)

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1"

resolvers ++= Seq("Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/")

resolvers ++= Seq("Sonatype Releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases")

dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
  "io.netty" % "netty" % "3.9.9.Final",
  "commons-net" % "commons-net" % "2.2",
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "11.0.2"
)

logLevel := Level.Error  // to suppress warning messages when compiling
```

I think is time to update the project to use the last sbt version, so I´ve changed to this `sbt.version=1.1.6`. After saving the file, Intellij IDEA have started to make some changes and I've got the following message:

Error while importing sbt project:

```
[info] Loading project definition from build.sbt:20: error: No implicit for Append.Values[Seq[sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID], scala.collection.immutable.Set[sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID]] found,
so scala.collection.immutable.Set[sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID] cannot be appended to Seq[sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID]
dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
^
[error] Type error in expression
Invalid response.
```

I'm super lost with this. Normally I only run the commands: `sbt compile` and `sbt package` and that's all. What are the steps to upgrade the sbt version on my project? Any help please?

Comment: `Set` vs `Seq`, perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just deleted the following part:

```
dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
  "io.netty" % "netty" % "3.9.9.Final",
  "commons-net" % "commons-net" % "2.2",
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "11.0.2"
)
```

and everything went well!

I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: It helps to know that `dependencyOverrides` became a `Seq` in sbt 1, so just changing `Set` to `Seq` should help. Removing overrides all together means you didn't need them in the first place (unless you also updated dependencies). You should check it with the `update` task.